# How do I generate COM interop proxies into C# source code?

Tags: c#, .net, com, interop

This questions is a follow up on an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796945/should-interop-assemblies-be-signed/796980#796980) by [Paul Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76456/paul-alexander) to the question ["Should interop assemblies be signed?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796945/should-interop-assemblies-be-signed).

> Depending on how complex your Interop assemblies are - you can generate the proxy code into a separate .CS/.VB file and compile it directly into your assembly. Then you won't have to worry about strong name issues.

How would I go about generating the interop proxy code for a COM library into C# source code?

I guess it could be done with tlbimp and then extracting the source with Reflector. Has anyone done this or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the following MSDN article:

- [How to: Create Wrappers Manually](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8fbsf00.aspx) (Talks about how to create your interop assembly manually.)

Once you've got the interop assembly, use a tool like [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to disassemble it and generate the raw C# source. [Reflector.FileDisassembler](http://www.denisbauer.com/NETTools/FileDisassembler.aspx) makes this really easy.

Now you can include the generated C#/VB sources directly into your assembly.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know simpler way, and extract interface descriptions via Reflector. However in VS 2010 Microsoft will do this for you [automatically](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2009/03/30/the-c-programming-language-version-40/).