# Do you strong name all assemblies your product uses?

Tags: .net, assemblies, strongname

I have a product which has around 10+ assemblies. We used to ship it without strongly naming the assemblies. But after reading about strong naming, I guess it is a wise idea to strong name assemblies. Just wanted to know is that a best practice to strong name all assemblies used by a program?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Here's another closely related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/796945/should-interop-assemblies-be-signed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is a best practice and you really ought to do it especially considering the fact that you are shipping this code to customers (I consider strong-naming to be less critical in an internal or web-based application).

For an explanation of this rationale please see  [Strong-Named Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wd40t7ad.aspx):

> A strong name consists of the
>   assembly's identity—its simple text
>   name, version number, and culture
>   information (if provided)—plus a
>   public key and a digital signature. It
>   is generated from an assembly file
>   (the file that contains the assembly
>   manifest, which in turn contains the
>   names and hashes of all the files that
>   make up the assembly), using the
>   corresponding private key. Microsoft®
>   Visual Studio® .NET and other
>   development tools provided in the
>   Windows Software Development Kit (SDK)
>   can assign strong names to an
>   assembly. Assemblies with the same
>   strong name are expected to be
>   identical.
>
> You can ensure that a name is globally
>   unique by signing an assembly with a
>   strong name. In particular, strong
>   names satisfy the following
>   requirements:
>
> - Strong names guarantee name uniqueness
>     by relying on unique key pairs. No one
>     can generate the same assembly name
>     that you can, because an assembly
>     generated with one private key has a
>     different name than an assembly
>     generated with another private key.
> - Strong names protect the version
>     lineage of an assembly. A strong name
>     can ensure that no one can produce a
>     subsequent version of your assembly.
>     Users can be sure that a version of
>     the assembly they are loading comes
>     from the same publisher that created
>     the version the application was built
>     with.
> - Strong names provide a strong
>     integrity check. Passing the .NET
>     Framework security checks guarantees
>     that the contents of the assembly have
>     not been changed since it was built.
>     Note, however, that strong names in
>     and of themselves do not imply a level
>     of trust like that provided, for
>     example, by a digital signature and
>     supporting certificate.
>
> When you reference a strong-named
>   assembly, you expect to get certain
>   benefits, such as versioning and
>   naming protection. If the strong-named
>   assembly then references an assembly
>   with a simple name, which does not
>   have these benefits, you lose the
>   benefits you would derive from using a
>   strong-named assembly and revert to
>   DLL conflicts. Therefore, strong-named
>   assemblies can only reference other
>   strong-named assemblies.